# Changing a logic in xsl 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a text string - "Parkering mva fri 30 stk 01.04.14 - 30.06.14", I want to get the date from the string separately.

What I did is :

```
    <xsl:variable name="Letters">              
 <xsl:text>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="S_Date">
 <xsl:value-of select="translate(STRING_VALUE,$Letters,'')"/>
</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($S_Date,'-'))"/>
```

This is generating output as - "30 01.04.14", I donot want 30 in this. What I should do to remove it.

Comment: This is not going to be simple - unless there is a **constant** pattern regarding the digits appearing before the (first) date; in such case you could skip them and continue to what's after the first space following them.

Comment: Yes you are right because we don't have constant pattern of a string and anything can exist before dates.

Comment: Can we add any other logic to work or match with a non-constant pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following. This will extract the first **word** (space-separated) that matches a pattern of ##.##.##.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="STRING_VALUE">Parkering mva fri 30 stk 01.04.14 - 30.06.14</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="first-date">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$STRING_VALUE"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="first-date">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="word" select="substring-before(concat($text, ' '), ' ')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="translate($word, '0123456789', '##########')='##.##.##'">
            <xsl:value-of select="$word"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, ' ')">  
            <xsl:call-template name="first-date">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, ' ')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```